# this.val() not working for textbox, but $('.selector').val() working

Tags: jquery

In my code, `$("#date")` is a textfield with jquery datepicker attached. In the code below, when I select a date, firebug shows this error `this.val is not a function`

```
$("#date").change(function(){  
    var mydate = this.val();
    alert(mydate);
});
```

But when I change `this.val()` with `$("#date").val()`, it works perfectly and alerts the selected date. Can anyone point out why `this.val()` is not working?

**EDIT**
Sorry, $this was a typo. I actually used this.val(), not $this.val()

Comment: you have $this.val in your code.  what about this.val?  I could be mistaken, but I think in this context _this_ is referring to the event, not the selector.

Comment: @Sparky You have to learn the difference between a DOM element object and a jQuery object.

Comment: @thescientist: Nope, `this` will refer to the object. If he wanted to get field's value the old school JS way, he would use `this.value`.

Comment: @thescientist: `this` referes to the DOM element. But `$this` is undefined here.

Comment: `.val();` is a jQuery method that works on a jQuery object (`$(this)`), whereas `this` and `this.value;` a 'regular' JS DOM element and method operating on a DOM element.

Comment: @Felix I never implied that _$this_ would work.  Just an early morning blunder about this.value vs. $(this).val

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` in your event function isn't a jquery object, it's a dom object. Address it as `$(this)` and it should work for you.

```
$("#date").change(function(){  
    var mydate = $(this).val();
    alert(mydate);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You should write

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

$this.val() should be $(this).val();

```
$("#date").change(function(){  
    var mydate = $(this).val();
    alert(mydate);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is an actual DOM element, and `val()` is a jQuery method - you can't combine the two. Use `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var mydate = $(this).val();
```